# TimescaleDB Top N function

Tags: top-n, timescaledb

I have been reading through the docs but cannot seem to find something similar to Prometheus' `topk` function.
Is there maybe a sort then limit?

As an example, lets say I wanted the top 10 hosts by cpu? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```sql
SELECT   *
FROM     hosts
ORDER BY cpu DESC 
LIMIT    10
```